# SFML: Vector2<double> can't compile

Tags: c++, templates, sfml

I have this code that I can't compile. It works fine if I replace `sf::Vector2<double>` with `sf::Vector2f`. I've tried `typedef`, but it didn't make any difference.

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

int main() {
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(200, 200), "SFML works!");

    sf::Vertex line[] =
    {       
        sf::Vertex(sf::Vector2<double>(10.0, 10.0)),
        sf::Vertex(sf::Vector2<double>(150.0, 150.0))
    };

    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        sf::Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
            {
                window.close();
            }
        }

        window.clear();
        window.draw(line, 2, sf::Lines);
        window.display();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The first error:

```
test.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
test.cpp:9:47: error: no matching function for call to ‘sf::Vertex::Vertex(sf::Vector2<double>)’
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sf::Vertex` constructor does not take double vectors, only float vectors. See the [documentation](https://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.5.1/classsf_1_1Vertex.php).

Comment: Why is `Vector2` template then? Looks useless now. Is there any way to use `double`?

Comment: It is templated because it is also used for integer and unsigned integer types, e.g. `Window::setPosition()` takes `Vector2i`, while `Window::setSize()` takes `Vector2u`. Double precision doesn't make much sense for things like drawing lines.